# Creating an image file of my Nexus 5

Tags: images

I have a report to write related to any  forensics case, so what i was planing to do is create an image file of my nexus 5 which has nothing in it ( as i did a factory reset). i was hoping to create an image file and look into the phone so that i could find something valuable. The issue here is i don't want to root the phone so i need an alternative to create a .dd file where i can look into any files. Any suggestions. And i would be happy to hear other ways to write a good forensics report on any case. 
Thanks

Comment: Is the bootloader unlocked?

Answer (score 0):

The only way to create an image of your device is using the recovery mode, but a custom recovery flashed find on Internet. The default recovery is not able to do a backup of the device. Flash a custom recovery then do a backup in it.